# ffmpeg extract channels without conversion

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm using the following ffmpeg command to convert a multitrack wav to multiple mono tracks:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav \
  -map_channel 0.0.0 a.wav \
  -map_channel 0.0.1 b.wav \
  -map_channel 0.0.2 c.wav \
  -map_channel 0.0.3 d.wav \
```

This works fine but it converts the channels to 16bit PCM:

```
...
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s24le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Stream #0:0 -> #1:0 (pcm_s24le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Stream #0:0 -> #2:0 (pcm_s24le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Stream #0:0 -> #3:0 (pcm_s24le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
...
```

I've also tried "-sample_fmt pcm_s24le" or "-sample_fmt s32" but both parameters were not recognized.

How can I extract the channels of a multiwav file without changing the bit depth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The encoder pcm_s16le is being used for your `.wav` output. This encoder only supports the s16 sample format (see `ffmpeg -h encoder=pcm_s16le` and `ffmpeg -sample_fmts`).

You can choose the encoder pcm_s24le:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav \
  -map_channel 0.0.0 -c:a pcm_s24le a.wav \
  -map_channel 0.0.1 -c:a pcm_s24le b.wav \
  -map_channel 0.0.2 -c:a pcm_s24le c.wav \
  -map_channel 0.0.3 -c:a pcm_s24le d.wav
```

Comment: Thanks a lot llogan, this works perfectly. I was not aware i could use the -c:a parameter for each map_channel...